# nginx proxy_pass with uri not working

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

The following proxy works elegantly resolving `http://my.org/` to the proxied address:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
}
```

However, adding a name in the URI breaks things and results in a 404 error:

```
location /luigi/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
}
```

Also tried rewriting but to no avail:

```
location /luigi/ {
  rewrite ^/luigi/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
}
```

`accesss.log`:

```
myip - - [24/Jul/2020:16:56:36 -0400] "GET /luigi/ HTTP/1.1" 404 513 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
myip - - [24/Jul/2020:16:56:36 -0400] "GET /error?src=404&ifr=1&error= HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://myurl/luigi/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
myip - - [24/Jul/2020:16:56:47 -0400] "GET /luigi/ HTTP/1.1" 404 513 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
myip - - [24/Jul/2020:16:56:47 -0400] "GET /error?src=404&ifr=1&error= HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://myurl/luigi/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-"
```

`error.log`:

```
2020/07/24 16:56:32 [notice] 107788#0: signal process started
2020/07/24 16:56:36 [error] 107789#0: *13 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/error" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myip, server: , request: "GET /error?src=404&ifr=1&error= HTTP/1.1", host: "myurl", referrer: "http://myurl/luigi/"
2020/07/24 16:56:47 [error] 107789#0: *13 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/error" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myip, server: , request: "GET /error?src=404&ifr=1&error= HTTP/1.1", host: "myurl", referrer: "http://myurl/luigi/"
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Hi tash, it could already help to add an '=' to the location, e.g. ' location = /luigi/ '. Should you run non-static content behind that location you might consider a ' location ~* ^/luigi/(.*)$ '. Some Nginx pros will probably correct me :). Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Expose `/luigi` app in the browser as an `/` (root) or `/luigi` on the backend server? Which one?

Comment: Hi @Toumash, I need to set up multiple `proxy_pass` against one public url. The first configuration I provided displays the Luigi server against `http://my.org`. However, when I have many of them such as Luigi, Dash, and a static html, I need a string in the URL that would differentiate among the above three. Hence the string `/luigi` comes. I think my answer to your question would be "expose `/luigi` app in the browser".

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
location ~ /luigi/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/$1;
}
```

This will capture the path after `/luigi` to a variable, and add the path to `proxy_pass` path.

You need to make sure that your application generates proper URLs in the links it creates. Often it is a problem that the application generates URLs like `http://127.0.0.1:8082` and one cannot set it up to generate proper URLs in reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: Hi @Tero, doing the above didn't help. Upon doing that, when I plug in `http://my.org/luigi/`, the URL gets rewritten as `http://pnl_servers.dipr.partners.org/static/visualiser/index.html`, yet I get 404. However, for my very first block, without any name after `/`, the URL gets rewritten as `http://pnl_servers.dipr.partners.org/static/visualiser/index.html#` (note the trailing #).

Comment: I think you are right about 
`and one cannot set it up to generate proper URLs`. In the process of rewriting and responding back to the original URL, there is a problem that hinders nginx to serve back.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the app is sending back a redirect to some other domain (perhaps the domain it is configured to use).

Comment: Then use the Host header https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352958/3711660

Comment: Hi @Toumash, I tried the following:

```
location /luigi {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

yet again, the url `http://my.org/luigi` gets rewritten as `http://my.org/static/visualiser/index.html` and results in error404.

While I don't know if I followed your suggestion right, any other bright idea?

Comment: what about the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080468/3711660

Comment: You need to figure out how to set the base URL in your application. This cannot be fixed in nginx.